# IAM Policy with action: autoscaling:AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups, Filters access based on the ARN of a target group is not working

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-auto-scaling

We have an autoscaling group with 2 target groups. We want to allow a team to Detach/Attach one of these target groups and prevent them from detaching/attaching the other one. So we build this IAM Policy Statement:

```
{
        "Sid": "AsgPolicy",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "autoscaling:AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups",
            "autoscaling:DetachLoadBalancerTargetGroups"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:autoscaling:*:${account}:autoScalingGroup:*:autoScalingGroupName/app-${env}-frontend",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "autoscaling:TargetGroupARNs": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:${account}:targetgroup/app-${env}-target/*"
            }
        }
    }
```

Even though everything seems correct, whenever I use the role with this policy to detach/attach the target group in the condition I get this error:

```
Detaching target groups failed
User: arn:aws:sts::11111111111:assumed-role/role-name/username is not authorized to perform: autoscaling:DetachLoadBalancerTargetGroups on resource: arn:aws:autoscaling:eu-west-1:11111111111:autoScalingGroup:ad6d28fa-b472-44e9-9ec4-e39bab5cd364:autoScalingGroupName/app-dev-frontend because no identity-based policy allows the autoscaling:DetachLoadBalancerTargetGroups action
```

I don't understand where is the issue.
The condition is important because only one target should be updated and not the other one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For permission statement to work properly, ”Resource” resource types specified should be supported by actions listed under “Actions”. Not every resource type can be specified with every action. If you specify a resource that is not valid for the action, any request to use that action fails, and the statement's Effect does not apply.

In your case, actions "autoscaling:AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups" and "autoscaling:DetachLoadBalancerTargetGroups" does not support resource-level permissions (shown as blank in the actions table under “Resource types” column of [Actions Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2autoscaling.html)) and you must specify all resources ("*") in your policy.

You can try with this policy:

```
{
    "Sid": "AsgPolicy",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "autoscaling:AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups",
        "autoscaling:DetachLoadBalancerTargetGroups"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
            "autoscaling:TargetGroupARNs": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:${account}:targetgroup/app-${env}-target/*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just tried this and it didn't work either :( thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for this issue, it worked perfectly:

```
{
    "Sid": "AsgDetach",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "autoscaling:AttachLoadBalancerTargetGroups",
        "autoscaling:DetachLoadBalancerTargetGroups"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
            "autoscaling:TargetGroupARNs": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*xxx"
        }
    }
}
```